# Why am I getting a compile error when I'm trying to create a list of a dynamic object at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, list

I've done some research and found that there apparently is an easy and understandable way to do this using reflection.

```
Type MyType = typeof(MyObject);
IList lst = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance((typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(MyType)));
```

I'm getting compile error. It's telling I do in fact need to supply the type to IList...
Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Why do you want to create a dynamic instance of `List<T>` if you can only access it through the non-generic `IList` interface?

Comment: because I'll need the list to invoke a constructor of some object that I will only know at runtime...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot this:

```
using System.Collections;
```

without it, it only sees `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, and therefore complains about that missing `T`.